# Rails 4 - Use include optimization without reloading object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**The main problem**

In Rails (4 here), it is ordinary to have a controller like this :

```
class Book << ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_book, :only => [ :show, :edit, :update ]
  before_filter :authorize_user!

  def show
  end

 private
  def find_book
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end
  def authorize_user!
    redirect if ...
  end
end
```

In the view, this object called some relations to display, like this :

```
<% @book.pages.each do |page| %>
  <%= page %>
  <% page.words.each do |word| %>
    <%= word %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I let you imagine all the queries needed to display all the words contained in my book.

**A first stupid solution**

This can be optimized in the controller, like this :

```
def find_book
  @book = Book.include(:pages => :words).find(params[:id])
end
```

But this `find_book` is also called in other actions which doesn't need all this informations (`edit`, `update` for example).
The second issue is that when the user can not see this book (by `authorize_user`), the informations are loaded too. And we don't need it.

**A more complex solution**

So a more complexe technic can be done :

```
before_filter :find_book_with_include, :only => [ :show ]
before_filter :find_book, :only => [ :edit, :update ]

def find_book
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
end
def find_book_with_include
  @book = Book.include(:pages => :words).find(params[:id])
end
```

The code is now less maintable, because the 2 methods `find_book` are doing the same basic function.
The second issue denoted above is always here.

**Another solution**

An other solution is to call optimization only in action :

```
def show
  # Previously call find_book
  @book = Book.include(:pages => :words).find_by(:id => @book.id)
end
```

Now, it's more maintainable, but 2 queries are done in `books` table to get the same book.

**My last solution**

My last solution is more complex, less readable, implies more reflection, but this is the last one I can purpose.

```
def show
  # Previously call find_book
  @book.pages = @book.pages.includes(:words).load
end
```

**And you ?**

Is there a more elegant solution, more maintenable, more readable ? It's not the first time I'm doing this, and I'm pretty sure it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's better to have a little bit of duplication rather than a bad/unnecessary abstraction. I would not be concerned with two similar lines. Having said that, you can make this work without sacrificing the semantics of `find` like this:

```
def find_book(&block)
  @book = (block_given? ? block.call(Book.all) : Book).find(params[:id])
end

def find_book_with_include
  find_book { |b| b.includes(pages: :words) }
end
```

If desired, it should be fairly easy to abstract this further and make it possible to chain things more than one level deep.